# Has mongoose fixed the index that is unique and sparse and can take null values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Most answers I have found are from old posts, I saw Partial Index but no good example on how to use it, also I initiate my index when I start up mongoose again cant find examples on how to set it up to work with Partial Index.

```
// db is read from a config file
mongoose.connect(db.uri, {autoIndex: db.autoIndex, useNewUrlParser: true});
```

The problem if I want a property like email to be optional also unique and indexed, but when I update its set to null or empty space even if I force it to be undefined and that causes a duplicate error.

This the solution I have came up with it works but is their any better way, here is my simplified model in all its glory

```
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    index: {unique: true, sparse: true}
  }
});
// this run when creating a new user
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.email === null || this.email === '') {
    this.email = undefined;
  }
  next();
});
 // this runs when updating a user
UserSchema.pre('update', function () {
  const update = this.getUpdate();
  let fix = {};
  if (update.email === null || update.email === '') {
    delete this._update.email;
    fix.email = true;
  }
  this.update({}, {$unset: fix});
});
// Also what about findOneAndUpdate method will I need a pre method too
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging deeper I finally solved it, using Partial indexes and setting a function for cases of empty strings which will throw duplicate error, so nulls will work just fine for undefined values and will be considered unique

```
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    index: {
      unique: true,
      partialFilterExpression: {email: {$type: 'string'}},
    },
    set: v => (v === '' ? null : v)
  }
});
```

Comment: You saved me as well, damn I was looking hard for an answer like this. Big kudo to you sir.